# Can I use 14/2 romex to carry load for two different lights if I mark neutral as red?

Tags: wiring, bathroom

I have two switches in the same workbox that are going to feed two different lights. Can I use one 14/2 to supply hot, neutral, and ground to both switches and another 14/2 that carries two load wires? (the neutral would need to be marked red) One of the switches goes to a combo fan and light which I would use a 14/3 to carry switched and unswitched power. The other light would get a separate 14/2.

The path the wires need to take is a bit longer than idea due to working within existing construction.

---

Update - added diagram. Note that I've oversimplified the drawing within the the workbox. The fan/light grabs hot and neutral from the incoming 14/2 supply (rather than the romex coming from the switches) and the light does similar, but just the neutral.

[image]

---

Update 2 - Closeup of wiring for switches. Originally I asked if I could omit the neutral from the romex returning from the switches but I think I've gotten a clear 'no' on that. This drawing reflects the advice I've been given to use a 14/3 returning from the switches.

[image]

Comment: Try as I might, I cannot find a non-contradictory interpretation of your description of the proposed wiring. Perhaps you could reword. Or better yet, post a simple diagram.

Comment: who ever comes after you might not survive this

Comment: You need one /2 to deliver power to the switch box, another from there to the light, and a /3 for two switched lines to the fan.   Your question seems to include all that.  It's not clear what your question is or what the additional /2 is for.

Comment: @jay613 sounds like the OP wants to split the 1st (incoming) 14/2 at the switch box, splitting a black hot to each switch (presumably with wire nuts and pigtails).  The the (outgoing) 14/3 would connect the black wire to the other terminal of Switch 1 and the red wire to the first (incoming) 14/2, as an unswitched hot (fan and light).  The 2nd (outgoing) 14/2 would connect to the other terminal of Switch 2 (light only).  (I assume neutrals and grounds would be nutted up together, as usual.)  Basically, the OP wants to split 1 incoming hot into 3 outgoing hots, with 2 of them switched.

Comment: @Huesmann your interpretation does not explain why a white would need to be marked red.  You're saying switched to one fixture, and both switched and unswitched to another using a /3, which is all quite normal.   Also not clear why a fan-light would need both switched an unswitched power. You're either using  a wall switch or a battery remote.  Or both, but then if the wall switch is off the remote should not work.

Comment: @jay613 whoops, you're right—I totally missed that.  Add me to the "confused about the OP's purpose" group.  S/he really needs to provide a diagram.

Comment: Seeing your diagram now, it's still not clear what you are doing.   Are the switches *in the box* shown in your diagram?   Or are they in a separate box somewhere else, and you *already* have two 14/2 cables joining the two boxes?  If they are in the shown box, why do you describe cables, like "14/2" to describe wiring within the box?  And why does your fan need both switched and unswitched power, can you explain that?  Do you have three different things to switch (two lights and a fan)?

Comment: @jay613 The switches are not in the workbox, the workbox is separate. 

"and you already have two 14/2 cables joining the two boxes" > No, I'm going to run the wire and I'm determining the correct choice.

"And why does your fan need both switched and unswitched power, can you explain that?" > The fan turns on via sensor so its always powered. It also has a built in light which will be controlled via switch. Yes, there's an additional vanity light that will be controlled by the second switch.

Comment: Your new diagram shows neutral running to each switch.  Are these smart switches, or just standard switches?

Comment: @Mark They're smart switches

Answer (score 10):

No, that is not allowed. The current flowing through a single cable or conduit must be balanced. Thus, the hot and switched hot to a switch must be in a single cable/conduit.

I overall issue is that the unbalanced current produces magnetic fields that causes excess heating.

Comment: I agree that the currents should be balanced.  But jow do the magnetic fields cause excessive heating?  In the cables themselves, or in some other object?

Comment: @SteveSh -- in any ferrous object that gets between the cables (such as a nail or staple), and the mechanism is basically the same as what happens on an induction stovetop

Comment: @ThreePhaseEd - Do you have a reference for that?  Because the eddy currents that would generated in the staple or nail (which is what causes the heating) are very small.  That would also mean that I couldn't stand beneath a high voltage transmission line (where the cables are separated) with having my belt buckle heat up.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do what you drew.

If you are running new cables between the "work box" and the switch box:

1. In a switch loop, the loop needs to be within one cable.  You have two loops, so two cables.
2. You should run two neutrals to the switch box so that each switch loop can use a smart switch, whether or not you intend to install them now.  Code requires you to install a neutral in the switch box.  I don't know if you are required to install one per switch loop but you should.

Here's how you can achieve it:

1. Install conduit, and run black, white, green, and two more colors for the lights.  If the boxes and conduit are metal you can skip the green.
2. Use two 14/3 cables.  Each cable carries power and a switch leg for one light and a neutral for a smart switch to control that light.  You can't use a common power or neutral wire between the cables because all the current within each cable needs to net to zero.

It's ok for the unswitched power to the fan to be connected directly in the work box.

There's another way to do it without conduit that does not create switch loops, if you can find 14/4+ground by the foot at a reasonable price.  Install a 14/2 and a 14/4.   The 14/2 provides power to the switch box.  Its neutral also serves to power both smart switches if installed.  The 14/4 provides power, 2 switched power, and neutral *back to the work box* and it is from there that you connect all the lights and fans.  *In this setup, your unswitched power and neutral cannot bypass the switch box to the fan*.  The fan's power, which shares a neutral with its light, must also share the neutral path back through the switch box.  The benefit of this approach is that you have a "real" neutral everywhere.

Comment: Note that you'd need 2 14/3s for approach #3 to work (since the smart-switch neutral currents need to be kept in the same cable each smart switch draws its power from)

Comment: [Would you?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/264194/65210)    Given the milliamps required by smart switches is that in fact required?  I thought that was worth its own question, and I'll correct the above accordingly.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel and jay613 I added a detail of the switch wiring. As best I can tell it would be sufficient to have a 14/2 and a 14/3.

Comment: @Rasputin in your second drawing, you have two smart switches (both have neutral connections) and you drew 4 wires in a bunch.  If that's a /4 cable you're good.  If it's a /2 and a /3 there is an [outstanding question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/264194/65210)  to which I don't know the answer.  If ThreePhaseEel is correct, you'll need two /3s and I'll correct my answer.

Comment: @jay613 Thanks for breaking that out into its own question. That said, I feel pretty strongly (yet would like confirmation) that the two switches on the same circuit can be fed by a 14/2. We're really just arguing about where the wire junctions end up - either closer to the switches or further away. Additionally, one could write down numbers next to each of the hot/load and neutral wires to find a way to create unbalanced current. I can't find a way to unbalance it.

Comment: @Rasputin -- the issue is that you have to be able to clamp a sensitive (leakage type) clampmeter around *each individual cable* and measure 0 (i.e. current going one way = current going the other), and the setup with the 2 14/2s cannot achieve that, *ever*

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Agreed, regarding the 2x 14/2. You had said that 2x 14/3 would be needed, in which case I'm interested to hear whats wrong with my second diagram. Your commend - https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/264176/can-i-use-14-2-romex-to-carry-load-for-two-different-lights-if-i-mark-neutral-as/264192?noredirect=1#comment536834_264192

Comment: I'm modifying this answer to use two 14/3 cables.  While I still "feel" the tiny draw from an enclosed smart switch could be an exception, there does not seem to be such an exception in code and the only responses we have from two knowledgeable people (ThreePhaseEel and Harper) are to use /3 cables for both loops.