# Do two switch loops to one box require two neutrals?

Tags: electrical, switch

If you run two switch loops from the same circuit to a single box do you need to run two 14/3 cables so that smart switches will utilize a neutral from the "correct" cable for their own power?  That power typically draws single-digit milliamps.

Or is it ok if one switch using a 14/2 loop utilizes neutral from the other cable for its own power consumption?

Assumptions:

- The two cables are on the same circuit, same breaker.
- No conduit or /4 cables ... those avoid the problem, but the question is, if you have two cables do they both need to be /3 ?

Here is a diagram, emphasizing this all occurs between two boxes on a single circuit, and highlighting the one connection to neutral that is quesitonable:

[image]

Comment: Think it is okay if all the neutrals are on the same circuit(breaker).  Run into code(and other) problems if you jump circuits(hot on one and neutral on another circuit).

Comment: @crip659 yes, that was an assumption that I'll state clearly.

Comment: The newer code calls to use /3 for switch loops, but 9 out of ten times the neutral is just capped off in the switch box, to prevent the problem of using /2 for the loop, but then find you need neutral.

Comment: As an alternative to your diagram, I wonder if it would be either more, or less, code compliant to use the 14/2 as SW1 Switched Hot and Neutral, and share the Always Hot from the 14/3 instead ... ?

Comment: @brhans no that splits the sw1 loop between the cables.  Not allowed.  Idea is to keep each circuit in one cable, looking for exception for tightly defined milliamp circuit.

Comment: Actually, this has got me wondering whether a two-switch-loop box needs two HOTS, if both will be powered from a single hot upstream... Probably yes for reasons of maintainability, to keep the intent clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they need separate neutrals.  The neutrals must be carried in the same cable with the related conductors, NEC 300.3.

AFCIs and GFCIs tend to keep you honest on this point. They can't go everywhere only because they don't sell models that self-power independently from the wires under observation. But regardless, 300.3 is saying if you put a clamp meter around any cable or conduit, it must read zero due to equal and opposite currents canceling each other out.

The most elegant method would be to put a divider in the box. Nothing should cross between branches except for safety ground.  Neutral is not ground.

Comment: *Same circuit*.   The imbalance is only between two junction boxes, only a few milliamps, and all on the SAME circuit/AFCI/GFCI.   I'll call it out more clearly in the question.

Comment: @jay613 A drawing might help ;-)

Comment: @Rasputin Touché!

Comment: @jay613 What does "same circuit" have to do with it? Also who's to say you don't put a GFCI or AFCI somewhere else instead or also?  You should be able to put a GFCI anywhere in the circuit and it should hold.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica "Same circuit" relevance is addressing your point here about xFCIs.  The neutral imbalance on the leg to the switch box will not be visible to them. There is no place you could put them where they would see it.  I'll add a diagram.   "Same circuit" also is to rule out two (or more)  questions similar to this one where there is an *unrelated* neutral available in a box where a smart switch is placed in a switch loop.

Comment: @Jay613 well, you "got me there", but it's only a practical implementation issue - you can't buy 3+ wire GFCIs nor GFCIs that power themselves separate from the wires they are observing.  If you could, then you could put GFCIs on the two imbalanced cables, and *of course they'd trip*.   A more accurate way to describe the concept is that if you put a clamp ammeter on any cable, it must read 0 amps because of currents being equal/opposite in the cable and canceling each other out.